# What change should I make in the Image Data Generator to solve the error?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, computer-vision, classification

I am trying to perform Mixup Augmentation (details [here](https://www.dlology.com/blog/how-to-do-mixup-training-from-image-files-in-keras/)) but I am getting a value error as follows :

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (47,128,128,3) (64,1,1,1)
```

Following is the MixupImageDataGenerator class definition that I am using :

```
class MixupImageDataGenerator():
    def __init__(self, generator, directory, batch_size, img_height, img_width, alpha=0.2, subset=None):
        """Constructor for mixup image data generator.

        Keyword Arguments:
            alpha {float} -- Mixup beta distribution alpha parameter. (default: {0.2})
            subset {str} -- 'training' or 'validation' if validation_split is specified in
            `generator` (ImageDataGenerator).(default: {None})
        """
        self.batch_index = 0
        self.batch_size = 64
        self.alpha = alpha

        # First iterator yielding tuples of (x, y)
        self.generator1 = generator.flow_from_directory(directory,
                                                        target_size=(
                                                            128, 128),
                                                        class_mode="categorical",
                                                        batch_size=64,
                                                        shuffle=True,
                                                        subset=subset)

        # Second iterator yielding tuples of (x, y)
        self.generator2 = generator.flow_from_directory(directory,
                                                        target_size=(
                                                            128, 128),
                                                        class_mode="categorical",
                                                        batch_size=64,
                                                        shuffle=True,
                                                        subset=subset)

        # Number of images across all classes in image directory.
        self.n = self.generator1.samples

    def reset_index(self):
        """Reset the generator indexes array.
        """

        self.generator1._set_index_array()
        self.generator2._set_index_array()

    def on_epoch_end(self):
        self.reset_index()

    def reset(self):
        self.batch_index = 0

    def __len__(self):
        # round up
        return (self.n + self.batch_size - 1) // self.batch_size

    def get_steps_per_epoch(self):
        """Get number of steps per epoch based on batch size and
        number of images.

        Returns:
            int -- steps per epoch.
        """

        return self.n // self.batch_size

    def __next__(self):
        """Get next batch input/output pair.

        Returns:
            tuple -- batch of input/output pair, (inputs, outputs).
        """

        if self.batch_index == 0:
            self.reset_index()

        #my_list = []
        current_index = (self.batch_index * self.batch_size) % self.n
        #my_list.insert(0,current_index)
        #print("current index" + str(current_index))


        if self.n > current_index + self.batch_size:
            self.batch_index += 1
        else:
            self.batch_index = 0
        #print("batch_index" + str(self.batch_index))

        # random sample the lambda value from beta distribution.
        l = np.random.beta(self.alpha, self.alpha, self.batch_size)
        print("l")
        print(l.shape)
        X_l = l.reshape(self.batch_size, 1, 1, 1)
        print("X_l")
        print(X_l.shape)
        y_l = l.reshape(self.batch_size, 1)
        print("y_l")
        print(y_l.shape)

        # Get a pair of inputs and outputs from two iterators.
        X1, y1 = self.generator1.next()
        print("X1, y1")
        print(X1.shape, y1.shape)
        X2, y2 = self.generator2.next()
        print("X2, y2")        
        print(X2.shape, y2.shape)

        # Perform the mixup.
        X = X1 * X_l + X2 * (1 - X_l)
        y = y1 * y_l + y2 * (1 - y_l)
        print("X")
        print(X.shape)
        print("y")
        print(y.shape)
        print("my_list " + str(my_list))
        return X, y

    def __iter__(self):
        while True:
            yield next(self)
```

Following is my code where I call the Mixup class and perform the actual augmentation :

```
# Create training and validation generator.
train_generator = MixupImageDataGenerator(generator=input_datagen,
                                          directory='data/train/',
                                          batch_size=64,
                                          img_height=128,
                                          img_width=128,
                                          subset='training')
validation_generator = input_datagen.flow_from_directory(directory = 'data/train/', target_size=(128, 128), color_mode='rgb', class_mode='categorical',batch_size=64,subset='validation', shuffle=True, seed=42)

print('training steps: ', train_generator.get_steps_per_epoch())
print('validation steps: ', validation_generator.samples // batch_size)
```

The output:

```
Found 3503 images belonging to 5 classes.
Found 3503 images belonging to 5 classes.
Found 1496 images belonging to 5 classes.
training steps:  54
validation steps:  23
```

I initiated the training and am showing the output from the 42nd step. All the previous steps had similar outputs.

```
42/54 [======================>.......] - ETA: 11s - loss: 1.3245 - acc: 0.4565
current index 3392
batch_index 54
\n l
(64,)
X_l
(64, 1, 1, 1)
y_l
(64, 1)
\n X1, y1
(64, 128, 128, 3) (64, 5)
\n X2, y2
(64, 128, 128, 3) (64, 5)
\n X
(64, 128, 128, 3)
y
(64, 5)
43/54 [======================>.......] - ETA: 10s - loss: 1.3227 - acc: 0.4557
current index 3456
batch_index 0
\n l
(64,)
X_l
(64, 1, 1, 1)
y_l
(64, 1)
\n X1, y1
(47, 128, 128, 3) (47, 5)
\n X2, y2
(47, 128, 128, 3) (47, 5)
44/54 [=======================>......] - ETA: 9s - loss: 1.3233 - acc: 0.4538 current index 0
batch_index 1
\n l
(64,)
X_l
(64, 1, 1, 1)
y_l
(64, 1)
\n X1, y1
(64, 128, 128, 3) (64, 5)
\n X2, y2
(64, 128, 128, 3) (64, 5)
\n X
(64, 128, 128, 3)
y
(64, 5)
45/54 [========================>.....] - ETA: 8s - loss: 1.3214 - acc: 0.4549
current index 64
batch_index 2
\n l
(64,)
X_l
(64, 1, 1, 1)
y_l
(64, 1)
\n X1, y1
(64, 128, 128, 3) (64, 5)
\n X2, y2
(64, 128, 128, 3) (64, 5)
\n X
(64, 128, 128, 3)
y
(64, 5)
46/54 [========================>.....] - ETA: 7s - loss: 1.3211 - acc: 0.4541
current index 128
batch_index 3
\n l
(64,)
X_l
(64, 1, 1, 1)
y_l
(64, 1)
\n X1, y1
(64, 128, 128, 3) (64, 5)
\n X2, y2
(64, 128, 128, 3) (64, 5)
\n X
(64, 128, 128, 3)
y
(64, 5)
47/54 [=========================>....] - ETA: 6s - loss: 1.3193 - acc: 0.4561
current index 192
batch_index 4
\n l
(64,)
X_l
(64, 1, 1, 1)
y_l
(64, 1)
\n X1, y1
(64, 128, 128, 3) (64, 5)
\n X2, y2
(64, 128, 128, 3) (64, 5)
\n X
(64, 128, 128, 3)
y
(64, 5)
.
.
.
.
.

53/54 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.3072 - acc: 0.4608
current index 576
batch_index 10
\n l
(64,)
X_l
(64, 1, 1, 1)
y_l
(64, 1)
\n X1, y1
(64, 128, 128, 3) (64, 5)
\n X2, y2
(64, 128, 128, 3) (64, 5)
\n X
(64, 128, 128, 3)
y
(64, 5)
54/54 [==============================] - 53s 986ms/step - loss: 1.3058 - acc: 0.4606 - val_loss: 1.2556 - val_acc: 0.4749

Epoch 00001: val_acc improved from -inf to 0.47486, saving model to GoDL-NP_CE_NLS_ABC-MIXUP.h5
Epoch 2/3
```

Thereafter, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (47,128,128,3) (64,1,1,1)
```

My observations are

1) All the steps except step 43 have the following shapes :

X1, y1
(64, 128, 128, 3) (64, 5)

X2, y2
(64, 128, 128, 3) (64, 5)

But step 43 has the following shape:

X1, y1
(47, 128, 128, 3) (47, 5)

X2, y2
(47, 128, 128, 3) (47, 5)

2) Before the first step of the training has begun, the data generator seems to have already moved ahead as can be seen by the fact that cuurent_index = 124 by the time step 1 is running.

3) I feel the images available for step 43 is only 47 rather than the expected 64 (equal to batch size). I say this because for step 47, current_index = 3456 and batch_index=0. Total training images size = 3503. So, the difference is 3503 - 3456 = 47. For the next step, current index = 0 and batch_index = 1.

So, I guess what I need is the following:

1. How to make sure that equal number of images are available for each step?
2. How to ensure that the data generator and the training are in sync ?

Comment: The amount of code and data here is just too much. You need a [mcve]

Comment: I feel the code and data is required because of the intricacy of the problem but I still edited out as much as I could. Please do have a look again.

Comment: I'm really not going to go through all of that.

Comment: Haha okay ! I have deleted some more of the info now.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this issue: https://github.com/Tony607/keras_mixup_generator/issues/1

You need to change the mixup generator so that it calculates lambda's size correctly for the last batch by using `X1.shape[0]`:

```
    # Get a pair of inputs and outputs from two iterators.
    X1, y1 = self.generator1.next()
    X2, y2 = self.generator2.next()


    # random sample the lambda value from beta distribution.
    l = np.random.beta(self.alpha, self.alpha, X1.shape[0])

    X_l = l.reshape(X1.shape[0], 1, 1, 1)
    y_l = l.reshape(X1.shape[0], 1)


    # Perform the mixup.
    X = X1 * X_l + X2 * (1 - X_l)
    y = y1 * y_l + y2 * (1 - y_l)
    return X, y
```